# Exclude all pages except a few?

Tags: menus

I have a bunch of pages and I only want to include 2 or 3 pages on my main menu. How would I do that? Currently my code looks like this:

```
wp_page_menu('include=156,572,542&sort_column=menu_order&echo=0');
```

If I am going to insert `exclude=x pages`, it wouldn't make sense because there's just too many of them.

Please no plugin recommendation. I've tried some but they conflict with other things I do in this regard.

**UPDATE**
Here's the full function:

```
function main_nav() {?>
<div id="access">
    <div id="sub-access">
        <div id="sub-sub-access">   
            <div class="skip-link"><a href="#content">"><?php _e('Skip to content', 'thematic'); ?></a></div>
            <?php echo preg_replace('/<ul>/', '<ul class="sf-menu">', wp_page_menu('include=11,13,7,9,4&sort_column=menu_order&echo=0'), 1);?>
        </div>
     </div>   
</div><!-- #access --> <?php
}

add_action('thematic_header','main_nav',9);
```

It's a custom version of Thematic's thematic_access() function. I don't know why it's behaving this way. I tried it on a new installation, it doesn't work still.

Comment: The code you have there should work. Are any of your pages nested? `include` will make the menu show only the pages you specify, and `exclude` will make the menu show all pages except the ones you specify. So you can't have both arguments.

Comment: None is nested. I really thought it wouldn't include pages other than the ones specified. Could it be the theme? Also I used exclude pages plugin prior to this, could it somehow affected wp?

Comment: how are you calling this function? change echo to 1 if it's not used as a argument inside another function. better post the entire code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
   ...
   echo preg_replace('/<ul>/', '<ul class="sf-menu">', 
       wp_page_menu(
         array(
          'include' => '11,13,7,9,4',
          'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
          'echo' => 0)), 1);
```

or

```
  ...
   echo preg_replace('/<ul>/', '<ul class="sf-menu">', 
       wp_page_menu(
         array(
          'include' => array(11,13,7,9,4),
          'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
          'echo' => 0)), 1);
```

btw, there are better ways to add classes to html tags than using regexes like this...

Answer (score 0):

The smarter way to do it would be to use WordPress 3.0's custom menus. replace wp_page_menu() with wp_nav_menu() and see how that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin claims to exclude pages from menus only, and provides a simple checkbox for excluding pages, perhaps it will help.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/